# Prove that $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y}{t-1}e^{y(t-1)} = 0$.

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

For the distribution $g(y)=ye^{-y}$ for $y\geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise, I have shown, through integrating by parts, that the moment generating function is:

$M_Y(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{ty}ye^{-y}dy=\left[\frac{y}{t-1}e^{y(t-1)}\right]_0 ^\infty-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t-1}e^{y(t-1)}=\left[\frac{y}{t-1}e^{y(t-1)}\right]_0 ^\infty +\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}$ given $t<1$.

However, I need to show that $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y}{t-1}e^{y(t-1)} = 0$ in order to conclude that the $M_Y(t)=\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}$. I am having trouble evaluating the limit and can not apply the product rule for limits since the two constituent functions of it do not both have a finite limit.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes but then I need to find $\lim_{y\to\infty} -y^2 e^{y(t-1)}$, which seems just as difficult (if I have applied the rule correctly). Applying the rule twice just increases the power of y for me.

Comment: Just to simplify the appearance of the expression, ignore the $t-1$ denominator and replace the $t-1$ in the exponent with an arbitrary negative constant. You can probably choose this constant as a function of $y$ that goes to zero as $y$ goes to infinity and use the Taylor series to show that the limit is zero. This proves it for any negative constant of larger absolute value, i.e. any negative constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that
>
> $$e^x\ge \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$
>
> for $x>-n$.  Then, for $x>0$, it is easy to see that
>
> $$e^x\ge \frac14x^2 \tag1$$

Using $(1)$, we see that for $t<1$ and $y>0$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{y}{t-1}e^{(t-1)y}\right|&=\frac{y}{|t-1|e^{|t-1|y}}\\\\
&\le \frac{y}{|t-1|\frac14 (t-1)^2y^2}\\\\
&=\frac4{|t-1|^3y}
\end{align}$$

whence applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{y}{t-1}e^{(t-1)y}=0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Change variables so $t-1=-p, p>0$. Parametrize $y=x/p$. As $x$ goes to infinity, $y$ goes to infinity, and vice-versa, so substituting this new value for $y$ into the original expression and sending $x$ to infinity preserves the original limit. It is common knowledge that $xe^{-x}$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity, and multiplying it by $-p^{-2}$ (recovering the original formula, rewritten in terms of x and p) doesn't change that limit.